# Magento Remove attribute filter from a category

Tags: attributes, magento-1.8, filter, filtered-nav

I have this request:

It's possible to remove a filterable attribute from a category?

`Example:` I have 2 item with 2 attribute set. One item is in category A the other is in category B
These two products have one attribute in common in the attribute set(Eg: example Color).

I want that the `filter on Color attribute appear for category A and not for category B`.

I need to split the attribute (Eg: ‘color_a’, ‘color_b’) and make one filterable and the other none? Or there is a solution to set only one attribute?

Answer (score 1):

The default filtering system cannot be set by category.
An attribute can be filtered or not. Simple as that.

If an attribute does not have values for any products in the current listing it will not appear in the filters.

So I guess you have to create 2 attributes like you said (`color_a|b`), And make `color_b` not filterable.

Also make sure that the products in `cateogry B` don't have values for the `color_a` attribute or it will appear in the filters